# Is it possible to renew the Spotify access token automatically?

Tags: api, spotify, access-token

I have searched a lot but I can't find the right answer.
I'm working with the Spotify Web API. The access token is only valid for 1 hour. I want to know if it's possible to renew the Spotify access token automatically? And if the answer is yes, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better solution what was find is: Login use [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow)
you will receive access_token and refresh_token - and when access_token expired  you can get new use refresh_token as describe in '7. Requesting access token from refresh token'